# Web Scraping in R (Getting piece of Information from a table)

Tags: r

Trying to study web scraping in R alone...

This feels really difficult without HTML knowledge.

```
crime_wiki <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_crime_rate")
crime_wiki %>% 
  html_nodes(".firstHeading") %>% html_text()

crime_wiki %>% 
  html_nodes("dl+ h2 .mw-headline") %>% html_text()
```

Above codes worked fine. I got what I wanted to get.

When I tried to get city names (from Albuquerque to Wichita), it didn't work.
I wrote

```
crime_wiki %>% 
  html_nodes(".jquery-tablesorter a") %>% html_text()
```

What did I do wrong?

Ultimately I want to do... When I click each city name, their linked pages seem to have the same format. So get the same piece of information from each page such as name of Mayor of all the cities in the table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code allowed me to get the city names:

```
    library(rvest)
    crime_wiki <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_crime_rate")
    crime_wiki %>% 
      html_nodes("td a") %>%
      html_text()
```

I'm not familiar with your use of ".jquery-tablesorter a". I used SelectorGadget to get the name of the nodes, i.e., "td a". Note that with the code that I've shared, I would need to remove the last 4 elements if I wanted only the city names.

Comment: I used SelectorGadget too and ".jquery-tablesorter a" was given in the toggle area. When I put my cursor in the area, it says "td a". I don't know when I should which (toggle box or cursor box)...