# R Web scraping https://www.binance.com/ main table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have been trying to build a web scraper in R to scrape the the main table on https://www.binance.com/. All i have so far is this:

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html("https://www.binance.com/")

binance <- url%>%
  # html_node()%>%
  html_table()%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Commented out the line in the code that caused issues

This pulls a table with headers but the data in the table itself is just one row with what looks like some sort of code I don't understand.

I have tried different types of logic and I believe the data in the table is actually a child of the table but the simple code above is actually the only one that I've managed to pull anything at all that remotely resembles the table.

I wouldn't usually ask such an open ended question but I seem to be stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: This has been Answered Already Please Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103268/web-scrapping-in-r-getting-piece-of-information-from-a-table

Comment: Is that the exact code you are using? I get the error: "Error: Please supply one of css or xpath" But it looks like this table might be filled in with javascript. You cannot scrape such pages without actually executing the javascript. `rvest` cannot do this. You'll need to use something like `RSelenium`

Comment: The OP's code is, indeed, broken @MrFlick. `html_node()` _needs_ a CSS selector or XPath and it must have been something errantly stripped out during the paste.

Comment: Binance has an [API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs) and they actively [discourage](https://www.binance.com/robots.txt) [scraping](https://www.binance.com/agreement.html) That particular table uses XHR requests to grab and then show data so you won't be able to use this naive code anyway. Folks who help to scrape may be subject to civil or criminal penalties depending on regional laws.

Comment: I commented out the line in the code that is causing issues

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that can be considered :

```
library(pagedown)
library(pdftools)
path_To_PDF <- "C:/test125.pdf"
chrome_print("https://www.binance.com/fr", path_To_PDF)
text <- pdftools::pdf_text(path_To_PDF)
text <- strsplit(text, "\n")[[1]]
text <- text[text != ""]
text

[1] "      Inscrivez-vous maintenant - Profitez de récompenses de bienvenue jusqu’à 100 $ ! (pour les"                                    
 [2] "                                                                                                             Racheter le cadeau"     
 [3] "      utilisateurs vérifiés)"                                                                                                        
 [4] "Achetez et tradez plus de"                                                                                                           
 [5] "600 cryptomonnaies sur Binance"                                                                                                      
 [6] "  Votre Adresse e-mail ou numéro de téléphone"                                                                                       
 [7] "                                                         Commencez"                                                                  
 [8] "76 milliards $                                                     + de 350"                                                         
 [9] "Volume d’échanges sur 24 h sur la plateforme Binance               Cryptomonnaies listées"                                           
[10] "90 millions                                                        <0,10 %"                                                          
[11] "D'utilisateurs inscrits font confiance à Binance                   Frais de transaction les moins élevés du marché"                  
[12] "Cryptomonnaies populaires                                                                                            Voir plus"      
[13] "Nom                                                                                  Dernier prix                      Variation 24h"
[14] "      BNB BNB                                                                            €286,6                            +1,09%"   
[15] "      Bitcoin BTC                                                                       €19 718                            -1,07%"   
[16] "      BUSD BUSD                                                                             €1,03                          +0,01%"   
[17] "      Ethereum ETH                                                                       €1 366                            -0,51%"
```